# From the Rails API docs, how can I know that ActiveRecord::Relation supports "collect()"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is a documentation-navigation question.

I'm looking at the [`ActiveRecord::Relation` API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html).

I know from experience that `Relation` supports `each` and `collect`.  Presumably it supports `Enumerable`, *but I can't figure out how I could know that from the docs*.

Am I missing something?  Nowhere in `Relation`'s docs does it say it includes `Enumerable`, and none of its mixins include it either.

How did `collect()` get in there, and why can't I see it in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Ruby after all. This kind of information can be answered very easily using `Method#owner` method :

```
2.1.2 :004 > Comment.where(value_new: "")
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."value_new" = ''
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
2.1.2 :005 > Comment.where(value_new: "").method(:collect)
 => #<Method: Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation(ActiveRecord::Delegation)#collect>
2.1.2 :006 > Comment.where(value_new: "").method(:collect).owner
 => ActiveRecord::Delegation
2.1.2 :009 > ActiveRecord::Delegation.instance_methods.grep /each/
 => [:each]
```

Now you get the *hints*, from where it is coming. Rest can be answered by browsing through source code. `Method#owner` can lead you to the correct path, that way. It is very *handy method* after all.

Now look this [`line`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4efb0f373047c44249bc6542fdf9969e4c63dd88/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L46).

```
delegate :to_xml, :to_yaml, :length, :collect, :map, :each ....
```

Comment: Holy crap.  I've been wishing Ruby had a method like that for years.

Answer (score 4):

> I know from experience that Relation supports each and collect

No, it doesn't.

It produces a vanilla array of itself with `to_a` when you invoke an Array method on it, and that array receives the `.each` or `.collect`.

See [Delegation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4efb0f373047c44249bc6542fdf9969e4c63dd88/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb), the module that handles this. Specifically, inside `method_missing`, where it invokes `to_a` and proxies the method through to that, returning the result.

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if @klass.respond_to?(method)
    scoping { @klass.public_send(method, *args, &block) }
  elsif array_delegable?(method)
    to_a.public_send(method, *args, &block) # <-------- Here
  elsif arel.respond_to?(method)
    arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow.  I did not expect dynamic delegation.  I'm simultaneously impressed and annoyed (as I often am with Ruby).  Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` includes `ActiveRecord::Delegation` which is responsible to delegate various methods to other objects. For our case, the important delegation is [the delegation of `collect` to `to_a`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c61893ceda2fb8807eb9a4b30ee65f4ff4af56a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L46). This definition effectively means that calling `relation.collect` is equivalent to calling `relation.to_a.collect`.

```
delegate :to_xml, :to_yaml, :length, :collect, :map, :each, :all?, :include?, :to_ary, to: :to_a
```

Please refer to the documentation of [`Module#delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) to learn more about how this delegation works in detail.

Now, [as we know](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a), `Relation#to_a` returns a simple array containing the relation's data. Thus, the `collect` method called is actually the one of the array.

This is indeed a bit hidden and involves a rather large amount of meta-programming and thread-safety issues, making it rather hard to document. For most relevant purposes however, a relation acts similar to a late-bound array and should be treated that way.